# WinForm Chart: Updating data point Y value

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I'm trying to create dynamically updated histogram using WinForm Chart control. During form load I set all points in histogram data range to 0 using this loop:

```
for (double i = 0; i <= UInt16.MaxValue; i++) {
    chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, 0);
}
```

After receiving data from measurement device I increase Y value by 1 in corresponding point by this code:

```
 Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
      int index = packet.Data.Max();
      chart2.Series[0].Points[index].YValues[0]+=1;
      chart2.Refresh();
      chart2.Update();
      logTextBox.AppendText(index.ToString() +"\n");
});
```

New values appears in the textbox but they don't appear on chart and the chart doesn't change in any way.

What I'm doing wrong? How to update Y value of data point correctly?

Comment: You do need the Refresh (not the Upadate) but otherwise the code to update the y-value is fine. Is it ever called? Does the logTextBox show the progress?

Comment: @TaW Yes, it's called, new values appears in logTextBox.  Removing Update and leaving Reshresh didn't help it behaves same way. 
Brosing NET framework source via ILSpy revalead that Refresh calls Update internaly.  It also revealed that setting YValues causses relevant series and  chartarea  to be invalidated, and on next screen refresh redrawn.

Comment: Well, setting the y-value alone will __not show__ without also calling Refresh or Invalidate. So, unless the y-values are too big for `1` to show I don't know what could be going wrong. Of copurse you did test the index value as well..?

Comment: @TaW Y-values are all 0 at start and increasing y-values doesn't cause any  change on displayed chart. The index value is usigned short and I set all points in usigned short range to zero in first snippet, so all possible values must fit. It just don't work for no apparent reason.

Comment: Hm, strange. I would next do a test by adding the code in the invoke lambda to a button click to see that it works from there.. (It does here, Invoke and all..!) - Also add the current y-value to the output! - Btw, unless you set a Maximum autmtomatic scaling makes sure all values always fit; I had meant that adding 1 to a value of 1000 will not show..